# wrap label and input in same div

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

I'm trying to wrap my `radio` input and its `label` in a single `div` but somehow it's not wrapping only the input. My code is:

HTML is :

```
<div class="payment_processor-section">
    <input id="input_0" class="form-radio" type="radio" checked="checked"  name="payment_processor" value="1">
    <label for="input_0">Credit Card</label>
    <input id="input_1" class="form-radio" type="radio" name="payment_processor" value="0">
    <label for="input_1" style="">I will send payment by check</label>
</div>
```

Jquery I am trying is:

```
$('.payment_processor-section input').map(function(index){
    $(this, $("label[for='"+this.id+"']") ).wrapAll('<div class="abc">');
});
```

Please help.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
$('.payment_processor-section input').map(function(index){
  $(this).next().andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="abc">');
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YR677/10/)

Comment: Oh perhaps because of the extra uneeded selector if you remove `$("label[for='"+this.id+"']")` and leave `$(this)` it'll be perfect

Answer (score 8):

Or http://jsfiddle.net/43jdq/

```
$('.payment_processor-section input').map(function(index){
 $(this).add($("label[for='"+this.id+"']")).wrapAll('<div class="abc">');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since javascript and jQuery there are various ways to achieve the same result, you could also use slice and a for in loop

```
var collection=$('.payment_processor-section *')
for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i+=2) {
      collection.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll("<div class='group'></div>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating @Alex Char solution for jQuery v3.0

```
$('.payment_processor-section input').map(function(index){
  $(this).next().addBack().wrapAll('<div class="abc">');
});
```

`.andSelf()` has been deprecated in v1.8 and removed in v3.0, you can use `.addBack()` instead.